# I got a StackOverflowError by SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, singlechildscrollview

I got an error while running my debug app and i do not know why this error is showing,  i tried excluding the `SingleChildScrollView` but another error showing up and i do not know how to solve it.

The Error i got:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification>:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
SingleChildScrollView
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _StringBase.indexOf (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:359:7)
#1      String.indexOf (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:1068:18)
#2      _StringAllMatchesIterator.moveNext (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:1445:24)
#3      _StringBase.replaceAll (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:649:35)
#4      StackFrame.fromStackTraceLine
#5      MappedIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:391:20)
#6      WhereTypeIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:869:20)
#7      new _GrowableList._ofOther (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:202:26)
#8      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:152:26)
#9      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28)
#10     Iterable.toList (dart:core/iterable.dart:470:12)
#11     StackFrame.fromStackString
#12     FlutterError.defaultStackFilter
#13     DiagnosticsStackTrace._applyStackFilter
#14     new DiagnosticsStackTrace
#15     FlutterErrorDetails.debugFillProperties
#16     DiagnosticableNode.builder.<anonymous closure>
#17     DiagnosticableNode.builder
#18     _FlutterErrorDetailsNode.builder
#19     DiagnosticableNode.emptyBodyDescription
#20     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap.<anonymous closure>
#21     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap
#22     WidgetInspectorService._nodeToJson
#23     WidgetInspectorService._reportStructuredError
#24     FlutterError.reportError
#25     _debugReportException
#26     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#27     Element.rebuild
#28     ComponentElement._firstBuild
#29     ComponentElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#36     Element.inflateWidget
#37     Element.updateChild
#38     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#39     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#40     Element.rebuild
...
...
#9597   ComponentElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (21 frames)
#9618   Element.inflateWidget
#9619   Element.updateChild
#9620   RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild
#9621   RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount
#9622   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>
#9623   BuildOwner.buildScope
#9624   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
#9625   WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget
#9626   WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 913 libraries in 748ms.
Reloaded 1 of 913 libraries in 514ms.
Reloaded 1 of 913 libraries in 503ms.
```

and this one:
[image: The Error]

The Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavigation(),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 35),
                  _appBar(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  const TitleText(text: "My wallet"),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  const BalanceCard(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  const TitleText(
                    text: "Operations",
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  _operationsWidget(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        )));
  }
```

TitleText widget:

```
class TitleText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double fontSize;
  final Color color;
  const TitleText(
      {Key? key,
      this.text = '',
      this.fontSize = 18,
      this.color = LightColor.navyBlue2})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text,
        style: GoogleFonts.mulish(
            fontSize: fontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, color: color));
  }
}
```

_operationsWidget:

```
Widget _operationsWidget() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        _icon(Icons.transfer_within_a_station, "Transfer"),
        _icon(Icons.phone, "Airtime"),
        _icon(Icons.payment, "Pay Bills"),
        _icon(Icons.code, "Qr Pay"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you include more about widgets like `TitleText`,  `_operationsWidget()`... You can provide the widget that will reproduce the same issue you are facing.

Comment: i have included the widgets, please check again

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the `Container` in `Expanded` Widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavigation(),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Expanded(                      // like this
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
```

Comment: it does'nt work